# Two persons make a single throw with a pair of dice.The probability that their throws are unequal is?

Tags: probability

> Two persons make a single throw with a pair of dice.The probability
>   that their throws are unequal is ?

How should I calculate the number of ways in which the throw can be equal?

Comment: Do you mean the sums are unequal?  Or that the (unordered) pairs of throws are different?  That is, are $2, 5$ and $3, 4$ unequal?

Comment: The latter @paw88789..

Comment: I think this needs clarification.  As the posted solution shows, many readers will assume that each player throws a single die, though I expect that is not the intent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Each of the two persons makes a single throw with a pair of unbiased dice.What is the probability that the throws are equal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1460864/each-of-the-two-persons-makes-a-single-throw-with-a-pair-of-unbiased-dice-what-i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probability that the sums are equal breaks into $11$ disjoint cases: Equal sums of $2$, equal sums of $3$,..., equal sums of $12$.

$P($ both sums equal 2$)=\left(\frac{1}{36}\right)^2$

$P($ both sums equal 3$)=\left(\frac{2}{36}\right)^2$

etc.

Add up the probabilities of all the cases, then subtract from $1$ to get the desired complementary probability that the sums are unequal.

Comment: I wasn't sure what your answer to my comment meant.  The probability of the sums being unequal is consistent with the answer of $\frac{575}{648}$ that you gave in a comment to another post.

Comment: Oh...i guess the wording in the question is itself wrong.You are right.Thanks a lot for the help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Probability that their throws are unequal = $1-$ probability that the throws are equal $$=1-\frac{(^6_1)}{(^6_2)}=\frac{2}{5}$$

Comment: I guess your answer is wrong....the answer given is 575/648

Comment: Maybe I made a mistake then, Fine I am checking. Do you find any fault in my line of thought?